# How to generate XML version other than 1.0 while marshalling with JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb, version

I have few XSD files and corresponding XJC files. The version number of all the generated XML files using JAXB should be uniform and should be picked up from either XJC or jaxb.properties file. I am not able to find the XML version number,JAXB is referring to.By default its generating 1.0.

Comment: There are only two legal version numbers for XML: 1.0 and 1.1. Is there any good reason you want to generate 1.1? Or have you perhaps misunderstood the purpose of the version attribute in the XML declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need to set the JAXB `Marshaller` into fragment mode using the `Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT` property.  Then write the XML header yourself.  The following example demonstrates how this can be done via StAX.

**Demo**

```
package forum7009289;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);

        XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamWriter xsr = xof.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
        xsr.writeStartDocument("1.1");
        marshaller.marshal(root, xsr);
        xsr.writeEndDocument();
    }

}
```

**Root**

```
package forum7009289;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?><root/>
```